# Why did firestore move from firestore.collection() to collection(firestore)?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

It used to be

```
db.collection("customersData").add({
      name: customerName,
      password: customerPassword,
    });
```

Now it is

```
async function getCities(db) {
  const citiesCol = collection(db, 'cities');
  const citySnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol);
  const cityList = citySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  return cityList;
}
```

And you have to import the methods seperately `import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';`.

What was the reason for this?
Is it possible to use the old way of writing still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What was the reason for this?

You can read about it in the [release notes for version 9](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_900_-_august_25_2021).

> This release introduces the new modular API, which enables tree-shaking, bundle size reduction, and other benefits. See [SDK versions 8 and 9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#modular-version) for more details.

> Is it possible to use the old way of writing still?

Yes, you can use any prior version of the SDK before the changes in 9.

Comment: Thank you very mouch, Doug! I've listed all versions with `npm view firebase versions` and installed `npm i firebase@8.10.0`